# How can i add a new method to the default RESTful methods in laravel 4?

Tags: rest, laravel-4

Is there a way to add a new method to the default RESTful methods without adding it in the routes.php file in laravel 4? Because i feel the aim will be defeated if i have to add it in the routes.php file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. You can do it only by creating new routes, linked to custom methods.

```
Route::get('photos/popular', 'PhotoController@method');

Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

..or you can limit routes in REST:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController',
                ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);

Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController',
                ['except' => ['create', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```